# spatial regression in Python - read matrix from list

Tags: python, spatial

I have a following problem. I am following this example about spatial regression in Python:

```
import numpy
import libpysal
import spreg
import pickle



# Read spatial data
ww = libpysal.io.open(libpysal.examples.get_path("baltim_q.gal"))
w = ww.read()
ww.close()
w_name = "baltim_q.gal"
w.transform = "r"
```

Example above works. But I would like to read my own spatial `matrix` which I have now as a list of lists. See my approach:

```
ww = libpysal.io.open(matrix)
```

But I got this error message:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/vojta/Desktop/INTERNET_HANDEL/ZASILKOVNA/optimal-delivery-branches/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/libpysal/io/fileio.py", line 90, in __new__
    cls.__registry[cls.getType(dataPath, mode, dataFormat)][mode][0]
  File "/home/vojta/Desktop/INTERNET_HANDEL/ZASILKOVNA/optimal-delivery-branches/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/libpysal/io/fileio.py", line 105, in getType
    ext = os.path.splitext(dataPath)[1]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/posixpath.py", line 118, in splitext
    p = os.fspath(p)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
```

this is how `matrix` looks like:

```
[[0, 2, 1], [2, 0, 4], [1, 4, 0]]
```

EDIT:
If I try to insert my `matrix` into the `GM_Lag` like this:

```
model = spreg.GM_Lag(
    y,
    X,
    w=matrix,
)
```

I got following error:

```
warn("w must be API-compatible pysal weights object")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/home/vojta/Desktop/INTERNET_HANDEL/ZASILKOVNA/optimal-delivery-branches/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spreg/twosls_sp.py", line 469, in __init__
    USER.check_weights(w, y, w_required=True)
  File "/home/vojta/Desktop/INTERNET_HANDEL/ZASILKOVNA/optimal-delivery-branches/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spreg/user_output.py", line 444, in check_weights
    if w.n != y.shape[0] and time == False:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'n'
```

EDIT 2:

This is how I read the list of lists:

```
import pickle

with open("weighted_matrix.pkl", "rb") as f:
    matrix = pickle.load(f)
```

How can I insert list of lists into spreg.GM_Lag ? Thanks

Comment: Can you tell me what you want to do with this matrix libpysal can't just be passed in a matrix without knowing what it's for. Usually, it's some distance weight or continuity weight, please check out https://pysal.org/libpysal/api.html for more.

Comment: @smerkd its a distance matrix. It tells you the distance between points. For example distance between X1 and X1 is 2km.

Comment: Could you please print the `w` and its type when it comes from the example?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to pass it to the `libpysal.io.open` method? If I understand correctly this code, you first open a file, then read it (and the `read` method seems to be returning a List). So in your case, where you already have the matrix, you don't need to neither open nor read any file.

What will be needed though is what `w` is supposed to look like here: `w = ww.read()`. If it is a simple matrix, then you can initialize `w = matrix`. If the `read` method also format the data a certain way, you'll need to do it another way. If you could describe the expected behavior of the `read` method (e.g. what does the input file contain, and what is returned), it would be useful.

<s>As mentioned, as the data is formatted into a `libpysal.weights` object, you must build one yourself. This can supposedly be done with [this method](https://pysal.org/libpysal/generated/libpysal.weights.W.html) `libpysal.weights.W`.</s> (Read the doc too fast).

Comment: see my edit please, I tried this, but it did not work

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I edited, how I read the list.

Comment: In `spreg.GM_Lag`, the `w` parameter is supposed to be a `libpysal.weights` object, which you apparently can build from a list of list with the `libpysal.weights.W` method. It should look something like this: `model = spread.GM_Lag(y, x, w=libpysal.weights.W(matrix))`.

Comment: but `libpysal.weights.W` does something different, doesnt it? if I understand it correctly, it computes matrix full of 1/0 based on neighbours.  And I want to use distances, not a neighbouring matrix.And I  already have distance in `matrix`.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I read it too fast last time! I'll edit this answer